# How do you make an email with multiple lines when developing for Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, email

I'm using Android Studio to create an app for the capstone project of my course. Mostly going well so far but I've ran into a small but I'm assuming minor bug but I have no idea how to fix it. I've created a fragment that allows for an e-mail to be created, but, when testing it with input on both my phone and my emulator the text for the email it doesn't create new lines when it reaches the border, instead it just continues, basically meaning the user cannot format an e-mail properly. Is there anyway to make it so the text automatically jumps to a new line when it hits a border like basically everything on a phone?

This is the XML for the email fragment:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="400dp"
android:background="@color/teal_200"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/subjectLineFrag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Subject Line"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/emailFrag"
    android:layout_width="343dp"
    android:layout_height="285dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter e-mail \n Don't include introductory line"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/subjectLineFrag"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.503"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/subjectLineFrag"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/subjectLineFrag" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is the code for the activity using the fragment

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_guest2);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, new EmailFragment());
    transaction.commit();//Needs to be applied at end of transaction
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for:

```
<EditText 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

Comment: Wish I could slam an embarrassed GIF in here. Yeah, had over enthusiastically dragged the email line over in the layout design section without ever noticing it was for an address. Thanks man, this was the ticket